# Make part of directory optional if it exists?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a script that pulls builds from a specified directory that I enter with sys.argv like this. The builds are either hardware or software, the problem is if its a hardware build there is an extra folder where "*" is located, how would I write the code so it works for both, without having to manually type the extra folder name as a sys.argv

This works for the hardware builds

```
 location = ('Z:\\server\\' + sys.argv[1] + '\\*\\' + sys.argv[2] + '*\\')
```

And this works for software builds

```
 location = ('Z:\\server\\' + sys.argv[1] + '\\' + sys.argv[2] + '*\\')
```

I need something that works for both.

So i'm entering something like this in command - 
myscript.py my/directory mac or myscript.py my/directory hardware(name)

Thanks Dan

Comment: What are you doing with this string after you make it?  Does whatever system you're using support the `**` syntax? `'Z:\\server\\{}\\**\\{}*\\'.format(*sys.argv[1:3])`

Comment: How does python know if it's a hardware or a software build?  Is there another arg passed in from command line, or could you add one in that specifies?

Comment: I'm just running max(files, key = os.path.getctime) in the specified location to get the latest build. Theres multiple hardware folders located within a folder at //*// and theres Mac and Win folders located also at //*// with the software builds

Thanks I will try ** see if it works.